# How to delete all labels from frame but keep menu/buttons? tkinter, python

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to python/tkinter and have been trying to delete all labels in the mainframe of my program. But I also want to keep the drop-down menu/buttons. I've tried 2 ways to accomplish this but haven't been able to get it:

```
def delete(): 
        Prideful_label.destroy()
        Doubtful_label.destroy()
        Scared_label.destroy()
        Anxious_label.destroy()
        Bullied_label.destroy()
```

1. ^^ This only deletes the last label placed in the mainframe. But nothing before it.

```
def delete(): 
    for label in mainframe.winfo_children():
        label.destroy()
```

2. ^^ This deletes the entire frame, including the menu/buttons so the program no longer works.

Below is the full program code:

```
from tkinter import *
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import random 

root = Tk()
root.title("The Book of Wisdom")
root.geometry("800x450")

wb = load_workbook('Book_of_Wisdom.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

mainframe = Frame(root)
mainframe.pack(padx= 10, pady= 10)
Main_Label = Label(mainframe, text="Book of Wisdom", font=("Day Roman", 35))
Main_Label.pack()

clicked = StringVar(root)
choices = {'Prideful','Doubtful','Scared', 'Anxious', 'Bullied'}
clicked.set('Choose Emotion') 

def delete(): 
    for label in mainframe.winfo_children():
        label.destroy()

# DROP DOWN MENU vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
dropDownMenu = OptionMenu(mainframe, clicked, *choices)
Label(mainframe, text="How are you feeling?").pack()
dropDownMenu.pack()

def change_dropdown(*args):
    global Prideful_label
    global Doubtful_label
    global Scared_label
    global Anxious_label
    global Bullied_label

    Prideful = ws['A2'].value, ws['A3'].value, ws['A4'].value, ws['A5'].value, ws['A6'].value, ws['A7'].value
    rand_Prideful = random.choice(Prideful)
    
    Doubtful = ws['B2'].value, ws['B3'].value, ws['B4'].value, ws['B5'].value, ws['B6'].value, ws['B7'].value, ws['B8'].value
    rand_Doutful = random.choice(Doubtful)
    
    Scared = ws['C2'].value, ws['C3'].value, ws['C4'].value, ws['C5'].value
    rand_Scared = random.choice(Scared)
    
    Anxious = ws['D2'].value, ws['D3'].value, ws['D4'].value, ws['D5'].value
    rand_Anxious = random.choice(Anxious)
    
    Bullied = ws['E2'].value, ws['E3'].value, ws['E4'].value, ws['E5'].value
    rand_Bullied = random.choice(Bullied)

    Prideful_label = Label(mainframe, text= rand_Prideful)
    Doubtful_label = Label(mainframe, text= rand_Doutful)
    Scared_label = Label(mainframe, text=rand_Scared)
    Anxious_label = Label(mainframe, text=rand_Anxious)
    Bullied_label = Label(mainframe, text=rand_Bullied)

    if clicked.get() == 'Prideful':
        Prideful_label.pack()
    elif clicked.get() == 'Doubtful':
        Doubtful_label.pack()
    elif clicked.get() == 'Scared':
        Scared_label.pack() 
    elif clicked.get() == 'Anxious':
        Anxious_label.pack()
    elif clicked.get() == 'Bullied':
        Bullied_label.pack()
        
clicked.trace('w', change_dropdown) 
# DROP DOWN MENU ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

clearButton = Button(mainframe, text = "Clear", command = delete)
clearButton.pack(padx = 50, pady = 50)

root.mainloop()
```

Finally, if you have any advice on writing this program more efficiently, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: It would help if you could create an example that didn't rely on an external spreadsheet. Can you illustrate the problem with a little bit of hard-coded data?

Comment: Yes, no prob. I'll get it up by tomorrow. Thanks for the answer and feedback!

Comment: @BryanOakley Your answer and solution works great! Really helpful and a lot more efficient code. So the excel sheet is just a bunch of bible quotes and some of them are pretty long, which is why I stuck with using the external spreadsheet data.

Comment: @CoolCloud Your answer did exactly what was asked and is working great! Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, the lables are all you want to destroy, you can write the `delete` function like this:

```
def delete(): 
    for label in mainframe.winfo_children():
        if type(label) == Label : # just Label since you used a wildcard import to import tkinter
            label.destroy()
```

what happens here is that the function checks whether the widget to be destroyed is a label and if it is, the widget is destroyed. Here is a sample code to show you how it works

```
from tkinter import *


def delete(): 
    for label in mainframe.winfo_children():
        if type(label) == Label :
            label.destroy()

root = Tk()

mainframe = Frame(root)
mainframe.pack()
lbl1 = Label(mainframe,text="hello")
lbl1.pack()
lbl2 = Label(mainframe,text="hello")
lbl2.pack()
btn1 = Button(mainframe,text="Button")
btn1.pack()
btn2 = Button(mainframe,text="Button")
btn2.pack()
delete()

root.mainloop()
```

on running this piece of code, you will notice that the lables are deleted but the buttons stay on the screen.
So your completed code should look something like this

```
from tkinter import *
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import random 

root = Tk()
root.title("The Book of Wisdom")
root.geometry("800x450")

wb = load_workbook('Book_of_Wisdom.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

mainframe = Frame(root)
mainframe.pack(padx= 10, pady= 10)
Main_Label = Label(mainframe, text="Book of Wisdom", font=("Day Roman", 35))
Main_Label.pack()

clicked = StringVar(root)
choices = {'Prideful','Doubtful','Scared', 'Anxious', 'Bullied'}
clicked.set('Choose Emotion') 

def delete(): 
    for label in mainframe.winfo_children():
        if type(label) == Label :
            label.destroy()

# DROP DOWN MENU vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
dropDownMenu = OptionMenu(mainframe, clicked, *choices)
Label(mainframe, text="How are you feeling?").pack()
dropDownMenu.pack()

def change_dropdown(*args):
    global Prideful_label
    global Doubtful_label
    global Scared_label
    global Anxious_label
    global Bullied_label

    Prideful = ws['A2'].value, ws['A3'].value, ws['A4'].value, ws['A5'].value, ws['A6'].value, ws['A7'].value
    rand_Prideful = random.choice(Prideful)
    
    Doubtful = ws['B2'].value, ws['B3'].value, ws['B4'].value, ws['B5'].value, ws['B6'].value, ws['B7'].value, ws['B8'].value
    rand_Doutful = random.choice(Doubtful)
    
    Scared = ws['C2'].value, ws['C3'].value, ws['C4'].value, ws['C5'].value
    rand_Scared = random.choice(Scared)
    
    Anxious = ws['D2'].value, ws['D3'].value, ws['D4'].value, ws['D5'].value
    rand_Anxious = random.choice(Anxious)
    
    Bullied = ws['E2'].value, ws['E3'].value, ws['E4'].value, ws['E5'].value
    rand_Bullied = random.choice(Bullied)

    Prideful_label = Label(mainframe, text= rand_Prideful)
    Doubtful_label = Label(mainframe, text= rand_Doutful)
    Scared_label = Label(mainframe, text=rand_Scared)
    Anxious_label = Label(mainframe, text=rand_Anxious)
    Bullied_label = Label(mainframe, text=rand_Bullied)

    if clicked.get() == 'Prideful':
        Prideful_label.pack()
    elif clicked.get() == 'Doubtful':
        Doubtful_label.pack()
    elif clicked.get() == 'Scared':
        Scared_label.pack() 
    elif clicked.get() == 'Anxious':
        Anxious_label.pack()
    elif clicked.get() == 'Bullied':
        Bullied_label.pack()
        
clicked.trace('w', change_dropdown) 
# DROP DOWN MENU ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

clearButton = Button(mainframe, text = "Clear", command = delete)
clearButton.pack(padx = 50, pady = 50)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list to store the required labels and use this list to delete them:

```py
labels = []   # hold the labels that will be deleted

def delete(): 
    for label in labels:
        label.destroy()
    labels.clear()

...

def change_dropdown(*args):
    text = None
    if clicked.get() == 'Prideful':
        Prideful = ws['A2'].value, ws['A3'].value, ws['A4'].value, ws['A5'].value, ws['A6'].value, ws['A7'].value
        text = random.choice(Prideful)
    elif clicked.get() == 'Doubtful':
        Doubtful = ws['B2'].value, ws['B3'].value, ws['B4'].value, ws['B5'].value, ws['B6'].value, ws['B7'].value, ws['B8'].value
        text = random.choice(Doubtful)
    elif clicked.get() == 'Scared':
        Scared = ws['C2'].value, ws['C3'].value, ws['C4'].value, ws['C5'].value
        text = random.choice(Scared)
    elif clicked.get() == 'Anxious':
        Anxious = ws['D2'].value, ws['D3'].value, ws['D4'].value, ws['D5'].value
        text = random.choice(Anxious)
    elif clicked.get() == 'Bullied':
        Bullied = ws['E2'].value, ws['E3'].value, ws['E4'].value, ws['E5'].value
        text = random.choice(Bullied)

    if text:
        lbl = Label(mainframe, text=text)
        lbl.pack()
        labels.append(lbl)
```